# Data validation list indexing

Tags: excel, vba, list

I have a sheet named ("Lists") which contains all the lists for data validation lists. I have two sheets sheet 1 and sheet 2. For particular cell I have gender selection in two different languages. If I select man in one sheet the corresponded translated word should appear on other sheet same cell. I have stored all language genders in two colums in lists sheet.

Comment: Vlookup the translate word using your table. `=vlookup([Sheet1 Selection], [List],2,0)` Sub in the list and the selection, this assumes the table in your list has the gender, and the translated word and nothing else.

Comment: What's your problem? Have you tried this and are seeing an error, or do you not know where to start?